# Perl regex remove number/punctuation combinations

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove all digit/punctuation combinations in a string separated by whitespace, i.e.,

```
$string = " 13-acetate 9-11 777 >3 ctl-54 2!3 ";
```

should become

```
$string = " 13-acetate ctl-54 ";
```

My attempt is as follows

```
$string =~ s/\s+[\d*[:punct:]>]+\s+//g;
```

But this is giving me

```
$string = " 13-acetate 777 ctl-54 ";
```

Appreciate pointers as to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to match the same space in two passes. You need to use lookarounds.

```
s/(?<!\S)[\d\p{Punct}\p{Symbol}]+(?!\S)//g;
```

I used negative look aheads and look behinds so that you don't need to add leading and trailing spaces to the input string.

Comment: Perfect. Also +1 for `\p{Symbol}`.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, That won't work if the match is at the beginning/end of string. Easiest solution is to normalize the spaces afterwards.

Comment: @ikegami: indeed, `(?:\s|^)` or `(?:\s|$)` in this case.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, No, that won't do. If you use `/(?:\s|^)...(?!\S)/`, then it will leave the space in `777 abc`. Similar case for using the other one. I repeat: The easiest solution is to normalize the spaces afterwards.

Comment: @ikegami: Why don't use `\p{XPosixPunct}`?

Comment: @Gnouc, No idea what that is. Easier to use Unicode classes.

Comment: @ikegami: From `perldoc perlrecharclass`, `\p{XPosixPunct}` matches things that `\p{Punct}` and `\p{Symbol}` match.

Answer (score 0):

As ikegami pointed out, your problem is that you were trying to match the spaces twice.

An alternative way to quickly fix your original regex is to create an alternation for your beginning boundary condition:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = " 13-acetate 9-11 777 >3 ctl-54 2!3 ";

$string =~ s/(?:\G|\s+)[\d[:punct:]]+\s+/ /g;

print $string;
```

Outputs:

```
 13-acetate   ctl-54
```

However, this method is flawed in that it does not allow for words at the beginning or end of the string to be stripped.  That's why a negative lookahead and lookbehind is superior when enforcing a boundary condition.

If you'd like to be fancy and remove the spacing around the words in an intelligent way, than the following would work:

```
$string =~ s{(?:\G|(\s+))[\d[:punct:]]+(?:$|(\s+))}{ 
    my @spaces = grep defined, $1, $2;
    pop @spaces;
    "@spaces"
}eg;
```

Outputs:

```
 13-acetate ctl-54
```